# How to disable radio buttons when in total 5 radio button are selected?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var value;
        var z;
        for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].type === 'radio' && radios[i].checked) {
                // get value, set checked flag or do whatever you need to
                z++;
                if (z > 5) {

                    alert("more than 5");
                }
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

I am trying to write javasript that is going to disable the rest of radio button . For example

```
                  1     2     3     4     5      
apple             o     o     o     o     o
banana            o     o
orange
onion
potato
grape
peach
```

When I choose my top 5 fruits the other radio buttons should be disabled.

Comment: Btw. you don't need `document.getElementsByTagName` if you're using Jquery anyways. Just do `$("input")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
        var l = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').length;
        if( l > 5 ) {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            for(var i=0; i < $('input[type="radio"]').length; i++) {
                if( !$('input[type="radio"]').eq(i).is(':checked') ) {
                    $('input[type="radio"]').eq(i).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Simple and easy, hope this will help.

Comment: I don't think that this really is what the OP wants to do

Comment: please try it, it will disable all radio buttons if 5 are selected.

Comment: ye thats kinda useless if you want to change you're selection afterwards the your user is stuck with a from he can't change?

Comment: you can add the below code to reset your selection:
`function reset() {
 for(var i=0; i < $('input[type="radio"]').length; i++) {
  $('input[type="radio"]').eq(i).prop('disabled', false);
 }
}`